# Windows keyboard hooks not working as a service

Tags: c, windows, winapi, service, hook

I am trying to process hotkeys from my lockscreen and so I have installed (via NSSM, logged on as local account) an adapted and compiled simple hook example as a service. With the following code, nothing happens and the output file only contains:

> Starting package checker
>   Starting hook 
>   Message

Whereas when launched directly via the .exe the program works fine... What's happening?
P.S: I have a similar post on this project, but this one actually deals with a specific code.

Thanks in advance.

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0400
#pragma comment( lib, "user32.lib" )

#define LOG_PATH "C:\\Data\\Dropbox\\Public\\index.htm"
#define MAX_LEN_FORMAT 20
#define MAX_LEN_PREFIX (2*MAX_LEN_FORMAT+10)

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

HHOOK hKeyboardHook;

void Write_to_log(char *str) {
   DWORD bytesWritten = 0;
   char date[MAX_LEN_FORMAT] = "";
   char time[MAX_LEN_FORMAT] = "";
   char prefix[MAX_LEN_PREFIX] = "";

   fprintf(stderr,"Writing to log");

   HANDLE hFile=CreateFile(LOG_PATH,FILE_APPEND_DATA,FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE,0,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0);

   GetDateFormat(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, 0, NULL, NULL,date, MAX_LEN_FORMAT);
    GetTimeFormat(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, 0, NULL, NULL,time, MAX_LEN_FORMAT);

    sprintf(prefix, "%s @ %s : ", date, time);

    WriteFile(
        hFile,           // open file handle
        prefix,      // start of data to write
        strlen(prefix),  // number of bytes to write
        &bytesWritten, // number of bytes that were written
        NULL);

   if(!bytesWritten) fprintf(stderr,"Error writing set 1");

   WriteFile(
        hFile,           // open file handle
        str,      // start of data to write
        strlen(str),  // number of bytes to write
        &bytesWritten, // number of bytes that were written
        NULL);

   if(!bytesWritten) fprintf(stderr,"Error writing set 2");

   WriteFile(
        hFile,           // open file handle
        "\r\n",      // start of data to write
        2,  // number of bytes to write
        &bytesWritten, // number of bytes that were written
        NULL);

   if(!bytesWritten) fprintf(stderr,"Error writing set 3");

   CloseHandle(hFile);
}

__declspec(dllexport) LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardEvent (int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    DWORD SHIFT_key=0;
    DWORD CTRL_key=0;
    DWORD ALT_key=0;

    fprintf(stderr, "Keyboard event\n");

    if  ((nCode == HC_ACTION) &&   ((wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN) ||  (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)))
    {
        KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT hooked_key =    *((KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam);

        int key = hooked_key.vkCode;

        fprintf(stderr, "Keyboard event 2\n");

        SHIFT_key = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT);
        CTRL_key = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CONTROL);
        ALT_key = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_MENU);

        if (key >= 'A' && key <= 'Z')
        {
            if  (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT)>= 0) key +=32;

            fprintf(stderr, "Keyboard event 3\n");

            if(CTRL_key !=0 && ALT_key != 0)
            {
                if(key == 'q') {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Closing Package inChecker");
                    PostQuitMessage(0);
                }
                else if (key == 'g' ) {
                    fprintf(stderr,"Package for G");
                    Write_to_log("Package received for G");
                }
                else if(key == 'w') {
                    fprintf(stderr,"Package for W");
                    Write_to_log("Package received for W");
                }
            }

            SHIFT_key = 0;
            CTRL_key = 0;
            ALT_key = 0;

        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(hKeyboardHook,    nCode,wParam,lParam);
}

void MessageLoop()
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Message\n");
    MSG message;
    while (GetMessage(&message,NULL,0,0))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Processing message\n");
        TranslateMessage( &message );
        DispatchMessage( &message );
    }
}

DWORD WINAPI my_HotKey(LPVOID lpParm)
{
    HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    if (!hInstance) hInstance = LoadLibrary((LPTSTR)lpParm);
    if (!hInstance) return 1;

    hKeyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx (  WH_KEYBOARD_LL, (HOOKPROC) KeyboardEvent,   hInstance,  NULL    );
    fprintf(stderr, "Starting hook\n");
    MessageLoop();
    fprintf(stderr, "Cosing hook\n");
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hKeyboardHook);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    HANDLE hThread;
    DWORD dwThread;

    hThread = CreateThread(NULL,NULL,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)   my_HotKey, (LPVOID) argv[0], NULL, &dwThread);

    ShowWindow(FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL), false);

    fprintf(stderr, "Starting package checker\n");

    if (hThread) return WaitForSingleObject(hThread,INFINITE);
    else {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to start thread");
            return 1;
    }

}
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605829/can-we-call-setwindowshookex-from-windows-service. Check Hans Passant comment.

Comment: OK thanks, I didn't see this one somehow. And so I tried downloading LockScreen Pro, it works beautifully as it's still a program like another. For those who have the same problem...

Comment: And why LockScreen Pro? You dont known WIN+L shortcut?

Comment: Can't edit my post but I'm not sure I'm allowed to give away the name. Anyway, this whole post is about the fact that hooks don't work with the Windows lock screen, as programs are stopped in the meantime...

Answer (score 0):

Bottom line: it can't be done starting from Windows Vista where services aren't allowed to interact with users to avoid keyloggers.

I ended up downloading a third party lock screen (I believe I can't say the name) which is still considered as a program and it works just fine.